# php username, password encoding and security issues

Tags: php, mysql

I recently learned PHP/MySQL and was trying to fetch some contents from the server SQL and put them in my HTML

```
<div id="fetched_content">
    <!-- data from PHP connection comes here -->
</div>
```

Now what i want to ask is please can anyone tell me how do i secure my username and password for the database provided for the connection.

```
define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
define("DB_USER", "user");
define("DB_PASS", "password");
define("DB_NAME", "widget_corp");
$connection = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
} 

// 2. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}
```

Now if I do it this way the username, password and table names are going tp be visible to anyone in the source code. How can i hide them?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: See the red box: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Now if i do this way the user and the password and the table names gonna be visible to everyone in source option

**No,No,No.** As long as your PHP is configured fine with the web server, your PHP source code will not be displayed to the user as HTML source code ever.

This following section will only contain the output that PHP generated, not the PHP source code

```
<div id="fetched_content">
    <!-- data from PHP connection comes here -->
</div>
```

Therefore your db login credentials are still secure, only except if someone breaks into your server and then views your source files but then if that happens it will happen no matter where you store the login information.

Answer (score 2):

The way you're storing the password is the only way to do it. You need to make sure the PHP file is stored in a place in your server where no-one can access it. How you do this depends on the server you're running, they're all setup differently.

You should also make sure that the mysql username and password cannot be used by an external IP address. It should not be possible to connect to your MySQL database from any computer in the world other than the one your PHP code is running on (for development work, use a MySQL client that supports SSH tunnels).

Some other things you're doing wrong:

- the password is way too short. Increase it to be 5 or 6 times longer than it is now.
- do not use mysql_* functions. Use PDO instead, and make sure you are using the "prepared statements" feature, which is the primary reason why you should be using PDO. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

And most importantly: *do not store secret data in the database*. Anything like passwords or credit card data must be hashed or encrypted with a strong industry standard algorithm. If you don't know how to do this properly, then ask here.

It is an industry standard security practice to assume hackers will occasionally gain full access to all of your servers. You need to design your database in such a way that a hacker gaining access is not a complete disaster. Encrypting the data is the only way to achieve this, and companies who fail to do so always end up with their pants around their ankles eventually.

Comment: Thank you for your time and valuable info , i will take care of these and by the way can you tell me how do i make sure that only my PHP code will connect to the DB and not any other IP address

Comment: @deadman best to search http://serverfault.com, but usually you would make it allow connections by socket only, and refuse connections by TCP. Our sysadmin has installed a hardware firewall that also blocks the TCP connections on the MySQL port, but you might not be able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You must have your db username and password in the source. How else would you connect to the db? So, the key is not how to secure your username and password, but *how to secure your source files*. You did a bad start by showing your credentials here.

You could use some encryption, have the credentials loaded from elsewhere, etc... But whoever has the access to your source files, will be able to find/track/decrypt the username and the password.

But PHP takes care of rendering only what's output from it, not the code itself, so as long as your server is running normally, you're safe. That's how we all do it.